# JPA Re executing same namedQuery with different parameters

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, named-query

I'm using openJPA as implementation, and i'm facing the following issue.

In one of our services, we use a namedQuery to select value in a range, so something like that:

```
query = "select xxx from xxx where xxx in (:param)"
```

This service / query is called by another process which is responsible of building/providing this  parameter value. Sometime - for bad reasons - this process give us a list with a length greater than the maximum one authorized by DB2.

So i'm wondering if it's possible for us to implement a mecanism to automatically split this parameter into several list of vlaues, execute for each internal list this namedQuery and then aggregate results before returning.

The main question now is: can i re-use several times my built TypedQuery to re-execute same request but with a different parameter value ?

Code example (For the example, not a real nor existing code):

```
TypedQuery<MyClass> query = em.createNamedQuery("myQueryName", MyClass.class);
foreach (...) {
   query.setParameter(...);
   res = query.getResultList();
   // Query re-executed and results are different ?
}
```

Is it a correct way to fix this kind of issue, if not is there any better (in term of performances) way to do this ?

Comment: You could simply put the `query` within the `while` loop.

Comment: of course, current code get the query in the loop, i just ask this question to know if it's possible and better (or not)

Comment: Is there no other way of doing this query? Can you not do a join with a simpler selection criteria? I would have alarm bells ringing if I'd blown this SQL limit.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. You must recreate the `TypedQuery` for each execution.

Comment: Could you expand your answer (any arguments / code in the [SVN repository](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openjpa/trunk/))?

Comment: Really? I can re-execute a named query with the JPA impl that I use (DataNucleus JPA) and all works fine. Perhaps you could link to the line of the JPA spec that says this should not work?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the spec doesn't address this bit of behavior.